# Lollipop Theme issue

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-5.0-lollipop, submenu

I am using sherlock action bar in my project, I have used Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/transparent</item>
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/transparent</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>   
    </style>
```

Problem :
I am getting light color menu with lollipop:

pre lollipop image :

[image]

Lollipop image :

[image]

can some one guide me, how can I get slimier menu color on both .

Comment: You must use **toolbar** which is introduced in support 21 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a style which extends from `actionbar` sherlock to change color of you `actionbar` with other properties.

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.ForceOverflow">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#ff000000</item>
    <item name="background">#ff000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#CC3232</item>
</style>
```

**For `TextColor` only**

```
<style name="YOURTHEME.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/yourColor</item>
        <item name="textColor">@color/yourColor</item>
</style>
```

Last resort Solution

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/yourColor</item>
```

Comment: how to change overflow menu text color ?

Comment: I created customized actionbar sherlock from, http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/
I have everything expected but not text color. I have tried yours and others solutions.
but its not working.

Comment: already doing this 
 <style name="Theme.mybasetheamname.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
  <!-- <item name="textColor">@color/white</item> -->
  <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
  <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>

Comment: then I think <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/yourColor</item> this is the onlly solution for you

Comment: you are awesome. thanks buddy. please update your answer. let me mark it . but I have some doubts why other params was not working

Comment: Great !!. Glad it worked out for you. I have updated my answer.

Comment: the chnage is causing some problem in the entire application. 
As I declared <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/yourColor</item> ,
now every edittext's text present in the app color is white .

Comment: you can use this  `<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/my_edit_text_style</item>
    </style>
 
    <style name="my_edit_text_style" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
    </style>`

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new styles.xml in a separate values-21 folder. There, you can define a specific theme/style that suits your needs for Lollipop devices only.

Comment: Thanks, But can't I do with older style files ?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. You can use the exact same one your posted, but with a different parent theme, for example

Comment: can  you guide me which parent should I target instead of Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `ActionBar` or `ToolBar` provided by `app-compat` library, instead of `ActionBarSherlock`.

ABS uses replacement Holo themes for older versions, which I guess hasn't been updated in a while.

Comment: true, but I can't shift to app-compat right now. I will do it later.
If you can suggest me some solution in actionbarsherlock that would be great