# Text color in overflow menu with ActionbarSherlock and Lollipop

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

In my app I'm using ActionbarSherlock (don't hate me, I'm transitioning to AppCompat, but it has to work in the meantime).

My theme inherits from `Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar` and up to and including Kitkat everything worked fine. Now under Lollipop the text of the overflow menu is black. How can I make it white again?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have same issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614962/lollipop-theme-issue
any help will be appreciated.